# Objects viewed across a body of water

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, perception

I'm sitting on the back patio of my lake house, (looking across the lawn and across the lake) and viewing the mansion across the lake... But when I go next door (flat lot), the house looks larger/closer. It's very freaky. I didn't believe my neighbor till she physically walked me over to see. I want to say that it's something to do with looking across my large lawn? Or because there seem's to be more water viewing it from my house?  It's killing me to have it explained.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really can picture the scene. Could you maybe add a bit more context and describe better what you are seeing?

Comment: I agree with Sito's comment. You should at least provide a bit more information about the relative positioning and height of the houses.

Comment: Maybe a similar reason as the [Moon Illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion)? Could be because of what's in the foreground when you look at the house over the water?